# What causes WriteFile to return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, file-io

We currently face the problem of a call to `WriteFile` (or, rather CFile::Write - but that just calls WriteFile internally) causing the Win32 error `5` `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

(EDIT: Note that we can't repro the behavior. All we have at the moment is a logfile indicating the source line where the CFile::Write was and containing as error ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED!)

(EDIT: The file is on a **local** drive and it is in fact a file and not a directory.)

Now, [WriteFiles's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't really help, and experimenting with a simple test-app yields the following results:

1. WriteFile *will* cause ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if it is called for a file handle that is not opened for writing (i.e. is opened for reading only).
2. It *will **not*** cause ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if

   - The handle is not valid or the file isn't open at all
   - The access *rights*, or the *write protected flag* for the file are modified **after** the file has been opened by the process. (If these are modified *before* the file is opened, then we never get to WriteFile because opening the file will fail.)
   - The file is somehow locked by another process/handle (This will at best result in error `32` ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION).

That leaves us with the situation, that apparently the only possibility for this call to fail if the file was actually opened with the read flag instead of the write flag. However, looking at our code, this seems extremely unlikely. (Due to our tracing, <strike>we *can* be sure that WriteFile failed and</strike>  we *can* be sure that the error is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, we cannot be 100.1% sure of the opening flags, because these are not traced out.)

Are there any other known circumstances where WriteFile (CFile::Write) would cause an ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED?

**Note**: To additionally clarify the context of this question:

- The file was *open*, therefore it can't be a directory or somesuch
- All tests I performed indicate that while the file is open it cannot be deleted, so the file should still have been there on the call to WriteFile
- The file is located on a local drive and not on a network drive.

I should add that we're running on WIndows XP sp3 and the app is compiled with Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: why can't you trace the opening flags? If you don't want to edit the code, just use process monitor to inspect them.

Comment: Sure we can add tracing. This only happens once in a while at a customer site. There's no way we will be able to add a debugger there.

Comment: File system filter drivers can also cause this, the most obvious example being anti-virus scanners (though there are others such as encryption, etc).

Comment: Tell your customer to stop using the SysInternals' Handle utility.

Comment: @Hans - Our customers using the Handle Utility would be like a carpenter tinkering with the internals of a car engine. Rather unlikely. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was

> What causes WriteFile to return
>   ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED?

and I stated in the question

> 1. WriteFile will cause
>      ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if it is called
>      for a file handle that is not opened
>      for writing (i.e. is opened for
>      reading only).

After adding further logging for the open flags and another incident, it turns out this was correct. The logging for the open flags shows that at the point of error, the file object was opened with CFile::modeRead and therefore we got ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Haven't found out yet which weird code path leads to this, but this just goes to show: Never trust your own code. :-)

(Oh, and btw. It wasn't `::WriteFile` that failed, but the `::FlushFileBuffers` API, but apparently that returns the same error.)

Answer (score 1):

There is about a dozen different situations that might result in ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. Internally, all WriteFile does is call NtWriteFile and map its (somewhat meaningful) NTSTATUS error code into a less meaningful HRESULT.

Among other things, ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED could indicate that the file is on a network volume and something went wrong with write permissions, or that the file is really not a file but a directory.

Comment: The file is not on a network volumje and it is in fact a file.

Answer (score 0):

if you can debug it, you should. it could be a million things:

- msdn is wrong (it happens a lot)
- some app (virus?) is hooking WriteFile and causing different behavior
- filesystem problem?
- something wrong in your logging, or observations

Comment: IMHO, this should have been a comment. Debugging the problem is not possible at this time.